# How to convert infix expression to prefix expression without using stack, array, programming language or implemetaion

Tags: data-structures

Someone tell me any algorithm or steps to be taken for converting infix expression to prefix expression without using stack, array, any programming language or implementation. Just simple human algorithms for Non CS Students.

If anyone have better algorithm or steps please specify and also try to solve it for me please... :)

(5+15/3)^2-(8*3/3*4/5*32/5+42)*(3*3/3*5/4)

Answer (score 0):

The "simple human algorithm" uses a stack. Consider the [Shunting Yard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm), for example. You can do that with paper and pencil. The "output queue" is simply the solution that you output. The "stack" is just a holding place. So when it says, "push onto the stack", imagine putting that value on the top of a stack of other values. When it says, "pop from the stack," imagine removing the thing that was on top.

When doing it with pencil and paper, dedicate a couple of lines at the bottom of the page for your output queue. Create a column on the right side of the page as your stack. Wherever it says, "write it to the output queue", write that value as the next value on your answer line.

The first time it says, "push onto the stack", write that value in the stack column, at the bottom. If you have to push something else, write it above that value. When it says "pop from the stack," erase the top value from your stack column, freeing up a space.

That really is the simplest reliable way to do things by hand.

I'll use the first bit of your example for a demonstration. Let's say you want to convert `(5+15/3)^2` to postfix. Using the instructions in the Shunting Yard article:

Your output queue is empty and so is your stack. The first token is `(`. The instructions say to push it onto the stack. So we have:

```
output queue:
stack: (
```

The next token is 5. It goes to the output queue:

```
output queue: 5
stack: (
```

Next is `+`. Since there is no token on the top of the stack, we just push it:

```
output queue: 5
stack: ( +
```

Next is `15`. It goes to the output queue

```
output queue: 5 15
stack: ( +
```

Next is `/`. It's an operator and there's an operator on the stack, but `/` has higher precedence than `+`. So according to the rules, we push `/` onto the stack:

```
output queue 5 15
stack: ( + /
```

Next is `3`. It goes to the output queue:

```
output queue 5 15 3
stack: ( + /
```

Next is `)`. The rules say to start popping operators from the stack until we get to the open parenthesis. Or, if we empty the stack and there's no open paren, then we have mismatched parentheses. Anyway, popping the stack and adding to the output queue:

```
output queue: 5 15 3 / +
stack: <empty>
```

Next token is `^`. There are no operators on the stack, so we push it.

```
output queue: 5 15 3 / +
stack: ^
```

Finally, we have `2`. It goes to the output queue:

```
output queue: 5 15 3 / + 2
stack: ^
```

And we're at the end of the string, so we pop all the operators and put them on the output queue:

```
output queue: 5 15 3 / + 2 ^
```

And that's the postfix representation of `(5 + 15/3)^2`.

The only tricky part is getting the operator precedence right. Basically, exponentiation is highest. Multiplication and division next, at equal precedence, then addition and subtraction at equal precedence. If those are the only operators, it's easy to remember. Otherwise you'll probably want a table of operator precedence handy so you can refer to it when you're working the algorithm. And the unary minus (i.e. `5 + -1`) require a special case. But really, that's all there is to it.

Comment: I need prefix conversion

Comment: @rizwanraza: Then just output the operator before the operands. The algorithm is basically the same.